# How to update Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: command-line, updates, gnome-terminal

How to update Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Did you mean, how to update ubuntu from terminal?

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific? Are you wanting to update from the Ubuntu terminal, or are you looking to make some update to the terminal itself?

Comment: It'll be usefull for me as well, if you give some more detail, if you can make the question a little bit more clear. In fact there's no such thing named "ubuntu terminal"; we have "GNOME Terminal" coming with Ubuntu as the default terminal emulator. If you are asking to update the system via terminal, its something else, as Chakra and Chris Wilson commented/asked above.

Comment: you need to edit your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use Synaptic if you're a beginner (I actually use apt-get but that's been covered above). Open Synaptic and search for the terminal program that you want to update. Check the box next to it and save your configuration. It's very easy to manage packages with Synaptic. Try things out and read the help files and you'll be an expert in no time.

Also, the Update Manager should run at startup and check for updates. You can run the update manager by itself and it will upgrade all of the packages on your system (or even upgrade to a new distribution).

Synaptic and Update Manager should give you what you need.

Comment: hm.. but what to do when update manager is not running normally ?

Answer (score 24):

execute this in a terminal :

**VIA APT-GET** :

Using `apt-get` command line tool

`apt-get` is the command-line tool for handling packages. You can use following command options:

- `apt-get update`: Update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources via Internet.
- `apt-get upgrade`: Upgrade is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system
- `apt-get install package-name`: install is followed by one or more packages desired for installation. If package is already installed it will try to update to latest version.

---

1. Open terminal and type following two commands (Application > Accessories > Terminal):
2. Get update software list, enter:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Update software(s) i.e. apply updates:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

Comment: this is more usefull than the accepted answer